# What has changed with admin.getPeer?

Tags: peers

`admin.getPeer` in the past returned something like this:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://cc92c3aff13bb5c81f8c4a172a3847d5c6c6874a0acd607cf37f0e8bbd643d851fe727ce35245bbe22e5fc246e1efe957dd66161924692898d231541307f6d4e@47.104.183.34:36590");
```

With recent updates it is returning something like this:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://2640824ef05d35d14b46cab77e814a2b367ae0ab7906b4d3f8aa624bfc3c4705@54.86.13.24:30303");
```

As you can see the new enode is much shorter than the original. Has something changed?

Answer (score 1):

A node generates a key known as the `nodekey` when it first starts up. This is an secp256k1, same as ethereum addresses.

Previously, the enode URI was `scheme://pubkey@ip:port`. This was [recently updated](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/17643) to use `scheme://keccak256(pubkey)@ip:port` instead.

Comment: How would we retrieve a properly formatted list of peers similar to what we used to do with the old pubkey? This used to work: admin.getPeers(function(e,r){r.forEach(function(i){console.log('admin.addPeer("enode://'+i.id+'@'+i.network.remoteAddress + '");')})})                 I am looking to retrieve a properly formatted list to use with admin.addPeer

Comment: geth 1.8.17 contains an `enode` field in `admin.peers` which already contains the full `admin.addPeer` compatible URI